# How to clear previously selected items in Navigation Drawer (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-compose-ui

I have navigation drawer with multiple menu Items. When I click on any item it gets selected (Inbox) with highlighted color . After that if I click some other items (flagged Mail) it also gets selected with highlighted color . But previous selected (Inbox) should be cleared (highlighted color should be gone).

Only one item should be shown as Highlighted at a time . In my case both items are being highlighted as selected .[image: ScreenShot]

```
@Composable
fun DrawerItem(
  folderItem: NewFolderTableData,
  index: Int,
  navigationState: DrawerState,
  submenuList: ImmutableList<NewFolderTableData> = 
  emptyList<NewFolderTableData>().toImmutableList(),
  onMenuClick: (String)->Unit
) {

  val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
  var selectedItemIndex by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
  }

  var showMoreSubMenu by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(false)
  }

  var showInboxSubMenu by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(false)
  }

  val title = if (folderItem.foldername == Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_SHOW_MORE) {
    if (!showMoreSubMenu) {
        Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_SHOW_MORE
    } else {
        Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_HIDE_MORE
    }
  } else {
    folderItem.foldername
  }

  NavigationDrawerItem(label = {
    Text(text = title)
  }, selected = title == selectedItemIndex, onClick = {
    onMenuClick(folderItem.foldername)
    if (folderItem.foldername == Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_SHOW_MORE) {
        showMoreSubMenu = !showMoreSubMenu
    } else {
        selectedItemIndex = title
        scope.launch {
            navigationState.close()
        }
    }
  }, icon = {
    val iconId = getFolderIcons(folderItem.foldername)
    if (iconId != -1) {
        Image(
            painterResource(id = iconId),
            contentDescription = folderItem.foldername
        )
    }
}, badge = {
    if (folderItem.foldername.equals(
            Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_SHOW_MORE,
            ignoreCase = true
        )
    ) {
        if (!showMoreSubMenu) {
            SetRightIcon(vector = Icons.Outlined.KeyboardArrowDown, foldername = folderItem.foldername){
            }
        } else {
            SetRightIcon(vector = Icons.Outlined.KeyboardArrowUp, foldername = folderItem.foldername){
            }
        }
    } else if (folderItem.foldername.equals(
            Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_INBOX,
            ignoreCase = true
        ) && submenuList.isNotEmpty()
    ) {
        if(!showInboxSubMenu){
            SetRightIcon(vector = Icons.Outlined.KeyboardArrowDown, foldername = folderItem.foldername){
                showInboxSubMenu = !showInboxSubMenu
            }
        }else{
            SetRightIcon(vector = Icons.Outlined.KeyboardArrowUp, foldername = folderItem.foldername){
                showInboxSubMenu = !showInboxSubMenu
            }
        }

    } else if (folderItem.foldername.equals(
            Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_TRASH,
            ignoreCase = true
        ) || folderItem.foldername.equals(
            Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_JUNK, ignoreCase = true
        )
    ) {
        SetRightIcon(vector = Icons.Filled.Delete, foldername = folderItem.foldername){
        }
    }else if(folderItem.foldername.equals(Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_ADD, ignoreCase = true)){
        SetRightIcon(vector = Icons.Filled.Add, foldername = folderItem.foldername){
            
        }
    }

  }, modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)


  )

  AnimatedVisibility(visible = showMoreSubMenu || showInboxSubMenu) {
    DrawSubMenu(subList = submenuList, navigationState)
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you implemented it now, each `DrawerItem` has its own `selectedItemIndex`. Once you click the item, it will be highlighted. However, clicking one `DrawerItem` does not affect the local `selectedItemIndex` of all other `DrawerItem`s.

So you will have to move the selection logic into the parent Composable. When you click a `DrawerItem`, update the selected index in the parent Composable. 
 You have not provided any code, but I will provide a generic example:

```
// move this declaration from DrawerItem into here
var selectedItemIndex by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}

ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet {
            Text("My Drawer", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
            Divider()
            DrawerItem(
                selectedItemIndex = selectedItemIndex,
                updateSelectedItemIndex = { newItemIndex ->
                    selectedItemIndex = newItemIndex
                },
                //... other parameters
            )
            // ...other DrawerItem Composables
        }
    }
) {
    // Screen content
}
```

Now, update the signature of your `DrawerItem` Composable as follows:

```
@Composable
fun DrawerItem(
  selectedItemIndex: String,
  updateSelectedItemIndex: (String) -> Unit,
  // ... other parameters
) {

    //..
    onClick = {
        onMenuClick(folderItem.foldername)
        if (folderItem.foldername == Const.MailFolder.TYPE_FOLDER_MAIL_SHOW_MORE) {
            showMoreSubMenu = !showMoreSubMenu
        } else {
            updateSelectedItemIndex(title)  // invoke callback function to update selection in parent
            scope.launch {
                navigationState.close()
            }
        }
    },
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently each `DrawerItem` has its own `selectedItemIndex` that can be set to true.
You should hoist that state out to `ModalDrawerSheet` so it only exists once.